# Apache serving files from an encrypted drive returns a 403 forbidden error

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, encryption, http-status-code-403, disk-encryption

I create a sparsebundle and mount it as a virtual drive for each development project I work on. This works great until I needed to add encryption to one of the projects for added security of my client's files.

When encryption is on Apache returns a 403 forbidden message. I was able to  get around it by changing apache to run under my user and group but that's very bad for the security of my macbook.

Is there a better way to allow permissions for apache to access my encrypted drive?

Comment: What permissions are in place for the mounted files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an encrypted disk image in OS X, it defaults to creating the enclosed volume with restrictive permissions -- the owner (whoever mounted it) gets full access, while group members and others get no access.  The web server normally runs as the _www system user, so it falls into the other/no access category.  You can check this easily at the command line:

```
$ ls -l /Volumes
total 8
drwx------   6 gordon  staff        272 Sep 30 11:30 Encrypted Volume
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root    admin          1 Sep 27 17:11 Macintosh HD -> /
```

The "drwx------" means it's a directory ("d"); the owner (gordon) is allowed read, write, and execute access ("rwx"), the group (staff) is allowed no access ("---"); and others are allowed no access ("---").

The simple solution is to open up the volume permissions to allow group and others read-only access with chmod:

```
$ chmod go+rX /Volumes/Encrypted\ Volume
$ ls -l /Volumes
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   6 gordon  staff        272 Sep 30 11:30 Encrypted Volume
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root    admin          1 Sep 27 17:11 Macintosh HD -> /
```

It's possible (but unlikely) that individual directories and files inside the volume also have restrictive permissions set, in which case you'll need to adjust them similarly.

Comment: That was it. I should have checked the permissions sooner.